# CardView like the ones used by Google Play

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview

[image]

I would like to ask if there is a relatively straightforward approach to make my CardViews in a RecyclerView behave like the ones used by Google Play (above). This CardView has these characteristics:

- The topmost and the bottommost cards have its corner radius applied to its respective position. (With the bottom card having a shadow like a normal CardView with enough elevation would.
- The rest of the items' corners are not rounded at all and only a little seam line in between items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily to do it by wrapping your recycler view with a card view instead wrapping every cell.

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="6dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

You need also a decorator that draws a divider.

```
public class LineItemDecoration extends android.support.v7.widget.DividerItemDecoration {

   public LineItemDecoration(Context context, int orientation, @ColorInt int color) {
       super(context, orientation);

       setDrawable(new ColorDrawable(color));
   }

   public LineItemDecoration(Context context, int orientation, @NonNull Drawable drawable) {
       super(context, orientation);

       setDrawable(drawable);
   }
}
```

Here is the drawable line

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:left="60dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/colorDivider" />
            <size android:height="1dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

You can use like;

```
mRecycler.addItemDecoration(new LineItemDecoration(getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL, ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.divider_cell)));
```

**UPDATE**

For ripple effect you can add this to background of your root view of cell.

```
android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
```

Comment: I see, I'll try it then :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip @Emre Aktürk . Now all I need is to add the Ripple effect.

Comment: You can check again. I have updated my answer. Do not forget to add clickable and focusable lines.

Comment: That solution will affect RecyclerView performance, isn't it?